# Alternative solutions to multilevel modelling due to level 2 and 3 not having enough clusters

Tags: r, mixed-models, multi-level, nlme, multilevel-analysis

I have been running some multilevel models on my data but have now been told my clusters are too small and I need to consider taking out two of the levels and add them in as covaraites (dummy variables).I gave this a shot and it didn't work.

To provide some background information, I have pre and post test scores as the outcome variable. I have the data in long format. I have been using nlme package.

I have children nested within classes nested within schools. My original model included participant (n=303), class(n=17) and school(n=10) as three levels of MLM for random slopes but I also added time for random intercepts.
Based on the new advice to take out class and school due to the nested clusters not being large enough, I was going to keep the participants in as random slopes and time in as random intercepts.

I am fairly new to R and also finding my feet with stats so apologies if I have made some simple mistakes.

I guess my questions are:
1. Is the new technique of adding class and school as dummy variables the best approach? I have read about using FEMs (fixed effect models) to be a robust method for clustered data but was unsure if that is corresponding to the method I am actually trying to run
2. Is there a way to get back the issues with my model and the outputs I am getting (Error in MEEM(object, conLin, control$niterEM) : 
  Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1)
I found when i took out either class or code it worked, but this is not really a solution.

Any suggestions, solutions or guidance would be really appreciated, thank you.

Old Model:

```
 model1 <- lme(MASSATTS ~ Time*Condition,
                data = cdata,
                method = "ML",
                na.action = "na.omit",
                random = ~ Time|School/Class/Code,
                control = list(opt = "optim"))
```

New Code:

```
 model1 <- lme(MASSATTS ~ Time*Condition + School + Class,
                data = cdata,
                method = "ML",
                na.action = "na.omit",
                random = ~ Time|Code,
                control = list(opt = "optim"))
```

`Error in MEEM(object, conLin, control$niterEM) : Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you share a sample of your data: `dput(cdata[1:20,])`? Also, I think you will get better answers for you first question on Cross Validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: My recommendation would be to use Bayesian hierarchical modelling for this using Rstan or Rstanarm. The details of why are better suited to Cross Validated, but Rstanarm particularly is super easy to use.

Comment: @Fino Hi, I have a really large data set, 88 variables with 606 observations. Sharing a sample of my code might be a bit messy on here. Is there a selection of it you owuld want to see in particular? Thanks for the recommendation with cross validated, I have asked on there too. Thanks!

Comment: @OlliePerkins thanks for your suggestion, I will have a look into how to do this!